# How to match two values in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, match

I have a notepad with values ​​such as:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
```

Then I did the maximum and minimum of the first column and now I want the value that lies in front of the maximum and minimum values ​​and puts them in a textbox.

code of max and min are here:

```
     public double calculaMaximo ()
     {
         for (int k = 0 k <array3.Length / 2, k + +)
         {
             if (array3 [k, 0]> Max)
             {
                 Array3 = Max [k, 0];
             }
         }
         tb_maxf.Text Max.ToString = ();

         Max return;
     }

     public double calculaMinimo ()
     {
         for (int l = 0, l <array3.Length / 2; + l)
         {
             if (array3 [l, 0] <Min)
             {
                 Array3 = min [l, 0];
             }
         }
         tb_minf.Text Min.ToString = ();

         return Min;
     }
```

Comment: "notepad" means: a multiline textfield in your GUI application?

Comment: your code isnt complete ... where are Max and Min defined? what kind of array is this? also clearly it won't compile, the fors are missing ;

Comment: array3 = new double[lines, columns];

Comment: Which .net version are you using? Consider using System.Linq namespace and use built in Min and Max operations.

Comment: i just put one piece of the code just for you can give some advices how i can make the  match the value that lies in front of the maximum and minimum

Comment: i'm using visual studio 2010 C# Windows Forms

Comment: What do you mean by "lies in front" , for example if you get the max and min from column 1 , (i.e 6 , and 1) which is the value you want to extract and put in a text box ?

Comment: So if the min is 1 "lines in front" is 2
And if the max is 6 "lines in front" is 7

Comment: I want to extract 2 and 7

<br> the first column is where I'm doing the max and min and the second column are the values ​​correspond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use arrays when you can use a sorted dictionary? take a look at this code example:

```
SortedDictionary<int, int> sd = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
sd.Add(1, 54);
sd.Add(5, 12);
sd.Add(3, 17);
sd.Add(9, 1);
sd.Add(2, 44);
MessageBox.Show("First: " + sd[sd.Keys.ElementAt<int>(0)].ToString() + "\nLast: " + sd[sd.Keys.ElementAt<int>(sd.Count-1)].ToString());
```